# Select Element whose ID is another element's attribute

Tags: jquery

From an element like this

```
<div class="menu" data-content="one">Start</div>
```

how can I select the element whose ID is equal to the value in the attribute `data-content`, `#one`?

**EDIT:**

I had tried like this and wondered...

```
$(".menu").on("click", function () {

    $this = $(this);
    $(".content.active").removeClass("active");
    $(".menu.active").removeClass("active");
    $this.addClass("active");
    $("#" + this.attr("data-content")).addClass("active");

});
```

I was missing a $ ..

```
    $("#" + $this.attr("data-content")).addClass("active");
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Did you run into problems with the code you have? Which ones?

Comment: Yeah, `this` is a DOM Element, but `.attr` is a jQuery method. The console should have shown an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing `this` is your div, simply use this selector :

```
$('#'+$(this).data('content'))
```

Comment: AFAIK, the `data()` method uses an internal store and not the HTML5-style `data-*` attributes. Use `attr('data-content')` instead.

Comment: @Jan: `.data` extracts the values from `data-*` attributes. *"As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object."* http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2

Comment: @JanKrüger After some digging, I found that jQuery's `.data()` uses the `getAttribute` fallback so it works from IE4. Unless a client request a working solution for IE3 users, you are quite safe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for example, you want html text of this div, that equals to `data-content`,

```
$('#'+$('.menu').attr('data-content')).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr("data-content")` to get the actual data-content attribute

```
var $div; // div.menu
$("#" + $div.attr("data-content"));
```